# django-ckeditor request dont get changes in form

Tags: django, django-ckeditor

I have one form called in ajax function, this function return one django form with one ckeditor field.

This field is displayed without problems, but when I make a request, the field value, dont sended in request, but if I make another, in the same form, with the same values, the value is update and is sended in request.

**My form field**

```
class EditCommentForm(IdeiaForm):

    content = forms.CharField(
        max_length=settings.COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT if hasattr(settings, "COMMENT_TEXT_LIMIT") else 10000,
        required=True,
        widget=CKEditorWidget(config_name='question')
    )
    comment_id = forms.IntegerField(required=True)
```

**My html template**

```
<form class="create-comment" data-group-class=".comment-group" data-ajaxform="true" data-toggle="replace"  class="create-comment" data-update="#{{ to_update }}" action="{% url 'comment:edit' %}" method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    <div class="comment-group create-comment-body{% if form.content.errors %} has-error{% endif %}">
        <textarea name="content" class="form-control"  placeholder="Deixe seu comentário">{{ instance.content }}</textarea>
        <span class="help-block"></span>
    </div>
    <input name="comment_id" value="{{ instance.id }}" type="hidden"/>
    <div class="create-comment-footer">
        <input type="submit" value="Editar" class="btn btn-primary">
    </div>
</form>
```

Comment: This solution worked for me :
http://stackoverflow.com/a/13330333/4972932